# Trigger for 2 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

this is a homework question, just to make it clear.

This is the relational schema:

- `PaperInvolvement` (`paperNr, academicId, paperRole`)
- `Academic` (`academicId, acadName, employer`)

So `(academicID)` is the primary key for `Academic` and `(paperNr, academicId)` is the primary key for `PaperInvolvement` table.

Here is the trigger that I am asked to do:

- On `PaperInvolvement` after insert, update
- On `Academic` after update
- Prevent any 2 academics who work for the same company are involved in the same paper in the opposite roles.
- Use stored procedure or cover it completely in trigger

There are only 2 roles available in this table, which is `Reviewer` and `Author`

This is what I have done so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_PaperInvolvement_1
ON PaperInvolvement
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS
(
SELECT a.academicId, paperRole, paperNr
FROM
(SELECT academicId
FROM Academic
GROUP BY employer, academicId) AS a
JOIN
(SELECT academicId, paperRole, paperNr
FROM PaperInvolvement

GROUP BY paperNr, academicId, paperRole) AS p_inv
ON a.academicId = p_inv.academicId
WHERE paperRole = 'Author' AND paperRole = 'Reviewer'

)
BEGIN
RAISERROR('Cannot have 2 Academics from the same company to work on
different roles for this paper.',16,1)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
GO
```

My question is, based on the requirements (what I have listed on the bullet-lists), is this the correct way to answer the question?

Comment: was about to say same thing, where did you get stucked?

Comment: I am asked to do a trigger based on the points I have listed above (on the bullets).

Comment: So an Academic can work in maximum one Paper? That sounds strange. Are you sure that the primary key of `PaperInvolvement` isn't `(paperNr, academicId)`?

Comment: Yes sorry, missed that one. I have fixed that part.

Comment: Would you be interested in a DRI solution (only FK and Unique constraints) and no triggers?

Comment: I'd love to, however the question forces us to apply triggers to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_PaperInvolvement_Modify
ON PaperInvolvement
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
begin
    if exists
    (
        select P.paperNr, A.employer
        from PaperInvolvement as P   
            inner join Academic as A on A.academicID = P.academicID 
        where P.paperNr in (select i.paperNr from inserted as i)
        group by P.paperNr, A.employer
        having
            count(case when P.paperRole = 'Author' then 1 end) > 0 and
            count(case when P.paperRole = 'Reviewer' then 1 end) > 0
    )
    begin
        raiserror('Cannot have 2 Academics from the same company to work on different roles for this paper.', 16, 1)
        rollback transaction 
    end
end
```